# DLE запрос в базу

Tags: dle, mysql

Добрый день.

Делаю запрос в базу так:

```
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . PREFIX . "_urls` WHERE zakaz_id='$zakaz_id' ");
    while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) {

}
```

Но вот в цикле мне нужно сделать еще пару запросов (уже по конкретной позиции)
Делаю так :

```
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . PREFIX . "_zakaz` WHERE id='$zakaz_id' ");
    while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) {
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . PREFIX . "_urls` WHERE zakaz_id='$row[id]' ");
    $poz = $db->num_rows();
}
```

Но вот после внутреннего запроса следующий цикл главного уже выдает не то (ну понятно почему)

Подскажите, кто знаком с архитектурой ДЛЕ, может есть возможность запросам задать идентификатор как-то?

Answer (score 1):

Класс MySQL в DLE использует встроенный по умолчанию указатель к базе данных. То есть кажддый раз при запросе к базе данных указатель меняется. Поэтому делайте так:

```
$rez1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . PREFIX . "_zakaz` WHERE id='$zakaz_id' ");
while ( $row = $db->get_row($rez1) ) {
    $rez2=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . PREFIX . "_urls` WHERE zakaz_id='$row[id]'");
    $poz = $db->num_rows($rez2);
}
```

Но такое желательно не делать. Можно обойтись одним запросом, как показал [[@SilverIce](/users/2993/silverice)](/users/2993/silverice)